# How do I generate a hash from an array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a hash from an array. Basically I want to take the unique string values of the array and build a hash with a key. I'm also trying to figure out how to record how many times that unique word happens.

```
    #The text from the .txt file:

    # **Bob and George are great! George and Sam are great.
    #Bob, George, and sam are great!**

    #The source code:
    count_my_rows = File.readlines("bob.txt")
    row_text = count_my_rows.join

    puts row_text.split.uniq #testing to make sure array is getting filled
```

Anyways I've tried http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html

I think I need to declare a empty hash with name.new to start I have no idea how to fill it up though. I'm assuming some iteration through the array fills the hash. I'm starting to think I need to record the value as a separate array storing the time it occurs and the word then assign the hash key to it. 
Example = { ["Bob",2] => 1 , ["George",3], =>2 } 
Leave some code so I can mull over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started,

```
h={}
h.default=0
File.read("myfile").split.each do |x|
  h[x]+=1
end
p h
```

Note: this is not complete solution